# How to find the border points of a particular shape

Tags: r, border, shapes, points, uniform

Suppose I have a irregular, random, shape generated from a dataset. How do I find points that are situated on the shape's border?

I am using R. Are there any packages in R for this purpose? For simplicity, just assume that I have a 2d dataset of points.

Comment: A [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) is the technical term for the "border" of your dataset.  Using "convex hull" when searching may help generate good results.

Comment: Noticed you haven't accepted an answer on any of your questions. Please do so by clicking on the V sign to the left. This will reward the people that were so generous to answer you, and tell other visitors the answer was helpful. See also the FAQ

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are looking for the `chull()` function to compute the convex hull of a 2D object, in package grdevices.

Here is the example from the online help:

```
require(stats)
X <- matrix(rnorm(2000), ncol = 2)
chull(X)
## Not run: 
# Example usage from graphics package
plot(X, cex = 0.5)
hpts <- chull(X)
hpts <- c(hpts, hpts[1])
lines(X[hpts, ])
```

[image]

Comment: impressive nice answer ratio, Andrie !

Answer (score 2):

These functions (packages) seem adequate:

- ahull ([alphahull](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/alphahull/vignettes/alphahull.pdf))
- convex.hull (tripack)
- chull (grDevices)
- in.chull (sgeostat)
- convhulln (geometry)
- convexhull.xy (spatstat)
- calcConvexHull (PBSmapping)